# roots in a root system which have nonzero coefficients with respect to each simple root

Tags: root-systems

If we consider crystallographic root systems, then for each $k$ such that $n \leq k \leq d-1$ where $d$ is the Coxeter number, it seems to be the case that there is exactly one root of height $k$ with nonzero coefficients with respect to each simple root.

It seems to work if you check it case by case, but I would be interested to hear of a general way of arguing the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not hold in general.  In type E6, for example, there are roots for which the "middle" simple root has multiplicity 2 and so does one of the two other simple roots corresponding to a vertex adjacent to it, while all the other simple roots have multiplicity one.

Comment: Is there any place on the internet or in the literature where all the roots in the $E_6$, $E_7$ or $E_8$ root systems are written out explicitly as linear combinations of simple roots?

Comment: Several places.  There are appendices to Bourbaki's Lie theory chapters 4-6, which are a standard reference.  I didn't have that ready to hand, and found them via google.  Here is E6, for instance: http://www.maths.nuigalway.ie/~pbrowne/personal/research/roots/e6_rt.pdf  Let me also record that I didn't feel like I understood the positive roots until I knew the "knitting" procedure from quiver representations, by which you can calculate the positive roots in a canonical order about as quickly as you can write the results down.

Comment: Do you have a reference for [the "knitting" procedure](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212733/roots-in-a-root-system-which-have-nonzero-coefficients-with-respect-to-each-simp#comment527744_212836)?

Comment: @LSpice Section 10 of Representations of Finite-Dimensional Algebras by Gabriel and Roiter; there are also versions on the web (e.g., https://eprints.lancs.ac.uk/id/eprint/155415/1/coelho_simoes.pdf). What is not so easy to find is a version explained for people who just want to know the algorithm, without the representation theory. I think this might be worth explaining and I could try to do so if you post a separate question.